# How to prepend the prefix "_" to all files in a folder, in a list of files [Python]

Tags: python

Every day I am running my script which outputs a log file. I have an external Hive table reading all files in the folder not having the prefix "_". Therefore, whenever I am running my script I would need to prepend "_" to all files in the folder which end with ".log" and do not have the "_" prefix already.

My folder structure is like this.

```
 -output
   -_data-2020-04-10.log
   -data-2020-04-11.log
```

And my code is currently like this

```
 if __name__ == "__main__"
     df = fetch_todays_data() #Returns dataframe
     if not [f for f in os.listdir(dataPath) if not f.startswith('_') and f.endswith(".log")] == []:
            fileset = [f for f in os.listdir(dataPath) if not f.startswith('_') and f.endswith(".log")]
            for f in fileset:         
                 #### prepend "_" to all files.

     dataframe_to_json_log(output_path+/'data-{}'.format(datetime.date.today())) #Help function that transforms dataframe to json_blob in output folder
```

How do I correctly prepend "_" to all files in `fileset`?

EDIT:

I did not know the meaning of append, it should be prepend.

Comment: First you could check if the file (f in fileset) starts with '_', which you seem to do correctly. Then you can use os.rename('originalFileName.log', 'newFileName.log'). You already know the original name of the file, so simply add a '_' to the end of it. Do you want the _ to be before or after the .log?

Comment: When you say "append _ to all files" you actually mean "prepend", right? "some_file.log" becomes "_some_file.log"

Comment: Hi, yes I thought append was prepend, sorry. It should be prepend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what TheMechanist has but without affecting files that already have the "_" prefix :

```py
import glob, os
fileset = [f for f in glob.glob("*.log") if not f.startswith('_')]
for f in fileset:
   os.rename(f, "_" + f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob :

```py
from os.path import basename
import glob, os
path = 'mypath'
os.chdir(path)
basename(path)
for file in glob.glob("*.log"):
     os.rename(basename, "_"+basename)
```

Comment: Couldn't you do this without basename? If you're iterating over all the files found in your `glob.glob()` call, you could just use `os.rename(file, "_" + file)`